# Why all cumulants of energy $H$ are proportional to the particle number $N$ (Kardar’s book 4.6)?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In the Chapter 4.6 of Kardar ‘s Statistical Physics of Particles. It claims that:

> In fact $<\cal{H}^{n}>_{c} = (-1)^{n}\frac{\partial^{n} lnZ}{\partial \beta^{n}}$ shows that all cumulants of $\cal{H}$ are proportional to N.

Where does this result come from? Why all cumulants of $\cal{H}$ is proportional to N?

Comment: It is in page 113 of the ,pdf copy http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~hyx/ref/Mehran%20Kardar-Statistical%20Physics%20of%20Particles%20(2007).pdf

Comment: looking for the definition of "cumulant I found this esoteric definition http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Cumulants .  actually it seems to me that the few lines you have **omitted** between the formula and the words give the derivation of  why this is so.